# Routing everything except a certain IP range through an OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: windows, linux, firewall, routing, openvpn

I've been working with my OpenVPN server for a while, and I have a rather interesting problem. I need to redirect **all** client traffic through the tunnel **except** for a couple IP's that need to be resolvable locally. The way I'm doing this is pushing these routes from the server:

### Server 'PUSH' directives

```
 push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" 
 push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8" 
 push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

I'm seeing that translating into these Windows routes:

### Windows routes occurring

```
Wed Aug 31 15:14:35 2011 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 5,ping-restart 30,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Wed Aug 31 15:14:35 2011 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.1.254

Wed Aug 31 15:14:40 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 199.[*.*.*] MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.254
Wed Aug 31 15:14:40 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.5
Wed Aug 31 15:14:40 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.5
Wed Aug 31 15:14:40 2011 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.5
```

I've hidden my server's IP beginning with 199 for security purposes.

### What I've gathered

I'm assuming that 0.0.0.0 is a kind of code for "everything," so I'm not sure how I could get this to work, but the general idea is that I need a specific IP range (`172.16.*`) to be resolvable on the LOCAL NETWORK (of the client) meaning it does **not** go through the VPN tunnel and the client can connect to `172.16.*` locally.

Is this possible? Routes can be executed through the command line, server "push" or client config options. **Any** way to get this to work while still routing other traffic through would do, really.

### Additional Info

I have the server running on Debian 64-bit and the client running on Windows 7 (although Vista needs to work as well).

Client/server configs can be provided **if needed**.

Comment: Technically 0.0.0.0 only means "everything" when added with a 0.0.0.0 netmask, or "/0". In your case, two more-specific routes (0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1) are added instead; the end result is the same (all addresses matched), but the added routes take priority over a "default" 0.0.0.0/0 route. You are still correct, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears as if after doing some more research, based on grawity's answer that more specific routes will take precedence, after the server's PUSH i can simply do a

```
--route [ip to bypass] 255.255.255.0 net_gateway
```

net_gateway as defined in the 'route' directive in the openvpn man page will resolve to the pre-existing ip default gateway

Comment: You can do a push for that route too : `push "route [ip to bypass] 255.255.255.0 net_gateway"`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add another route, and it will take precedence over less-specific ones:

`172.16.*` translates to `172.16.0.0` with netmask `255.255.0.0`:

```
route add 172.16.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 if index
```

where *index* is the index of your LAN network interface as shown by `route print`. For example, `0x3` or similar.

Comment: But you have to know the interface. That also means the VPN server does not push the route itself.